# Loading JS in Django

Tags: python, django

I am very new in Django, I want to create a navtab using bootstrap and I have already created an static file, I actually could read the CSS file, but the JS interaction is not working.

This is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 {% load staticfiles %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Quant Consulting</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I cannot see any interaction on the development server, anybody knows why?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: (0) try to put codes in document.ready? (1) Did you change the settings.py file to include static root? (2) try `{% load static %}` or `{% load staticfiles %}` outside header?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? any errors in the console? invalid results?